# Can't load views in AppScript test deployment because of XFrameOptions 'sameorigin'

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to deploy a Web App using Google AppScript with multiple views. I have an appCover.html with a few buttons and each button redirects to a different page. The app cover (or homepage) loads flawlessly but when I click on any of the buttons I get the error in the console:

> Refused to display
> 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/sriptID/dev?v=newPage'
> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

I have looked into Google's developer resources and all the references I found tell to add the `XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL`. So I did but still no success. This is the function that is rendering each page:

```
function render(file, argsObject) {
  var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
  
  if (argsObject) {
    var keys = Object.keys(argsObject);
    
    keys.forEach(key => {
      tmp.key = argsObject[key];  
    });
  }
  return tmp.evaluate().setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}
```

Right now I am testing the deployment so I get `/dev` at the end when retrieving the URL and try to route with a parameter like `/dev?v=newPage`. Does it make a difference tying to access these pages when testing the deployment versus deploying itself?
It's a personal app so I'm the only user.
Any other ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: If you haven't already solved this, can you post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) taking into account ziganotschka's comments about not using the test deployment?

Answer (score 0):

### The problem is that you are using the `dev` version

Deploy your Webapp as an `exec` version

https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXX/scriptID

and then build your URL as

https://script.google.com/macros/s/sriptID/exec?v=newPage

Once you deploy your Webapp as a `exec` version, the method `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` will return you the corerct (`exec`) URL which you can use as a variable to dynamically build your redirection to different pages / views.

Comment: So in other words I can't use `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` during the test deployment? I am confused now because after I deployed as `/exec`, I use the correct URL to access the webApp but the variables for dynamically getting the URLs are creating a different URL to redirect like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/weirdScriptId/exec?v=newPage` and I get a server 400 error on these pages

Comment: If you do use ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() during development, it will return you the `dev` version instead of the `exec` version of the URL which is restricted and does not allow you the redirection. There is nothing wrong with using the `exec` version during the development process.

Comment: So basically during development I should hardcode the `exec` version or just manually access the pages individually? Also do you know about the different URL being picked up by the `.getUrl()` method in the deployed version? It doesn't match with the webApp `/exec` URL

Comment: No, hardcoding won't work. You should simply [deploy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploy_a_script_as_a_web_app) the Webapp - which is really simple.

Comment: So I should deploy it as a WebApp and while using the "Test deployment" the `ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()` should get the proper URL? I'm sorry for the confusion but also do you know why a different URL with different ID and still `/exec` is getting back from the redirects?

Comment: Basically - do not use "test deployment" - just deloy it as a WebApp and test it by copy-pasting the WebApp url (the exec one ) into your browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229214/discussion-between-everspader-and-ziganotschka).